# Django | Enter a valid date

Tags: python, django

Al insertar la fecha devuelve error: Enter a valid date

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Models.py**

```
class Consumable(models.Model):
    datetime_placement_consumable = models.DateField ('FechaColocacion',null=True, blank=True)
    ...

    class meta:
        verbose_name = 'Consumible'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Consumibles'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.serial_num_consumable) + '' + str(self.type_model_consumable) + '' + str(self.status_consumable)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class AddConsumableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Consumable
        fields = ('__all__')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddConsumableForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['datetime_placement_consumable'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','value':'','id':'datepicker'})
        self.fields['datetime_placement_consumable'].label="Fecha colocación del consumible"
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-lg-0 col-2"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">
            <div class="alert border m-3 bg-light" role="alert">         
                <h3>Nuevo Consumible</h3>
                <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p}}
                    <button class="form-control btn-dark mb-5" type="submit">Guardar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offser-lg-0 col-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
 
    $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
    closeText: 'Cerrar',
    prevText: '< Ant',
    nextText: 'Sig >',
    currentText: 'Hoy',
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
   $(function () {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
   });
   
   
   
     $( function() {
       $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
     } );
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto el formato que acepta Django para campos de fecha es: yyyy-mm-dd

Para aceptar ese formato lo puedes definir de manera global asi en tu settings:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%d/%m/%Y',  # '21/03/2014'
)
```

Si solo quieres aceptarlo en un campo, en tu form se hace de esta manera:

```
class AddConsumableForm(forms.ModelForm):

    datetime_placement_consumable = forms.DateField(label='Fecha colocación del consumible',
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs={'class': "form-control"}), 
                       input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])

    class Meta:
        model = Consumable
        fields = ('__all__')
```